# Data Augmentation in CNN creating Duplicates

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I am trying to do Data Augmentation on the ISIC The International Skin Imaging Collaboration Skin Cancer Dataset in google colab.

For some reason, it is only creating duplicates of the images and carrying out the RandomFlip, RandomZoom & RandoRotation operations.

This is the code I am trying to use

```
    data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
  [
    layers.RandomFlip('horizontal_and_vertical',
                      input_shape = (img_height,
                                     img_width,
                                     3)),
    layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
    layers.RandomZoom(0.2),
  ]
)
```

When I try to visualise the augmented data using the following code it only shows 9 copies of the same image.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for images, _ in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    augmented_images = data_augmentation(images)
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(augmented_images[0].numpy().astype('uint8'))
    plt.axis('off')
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

plt.imshow(augmented_images[0].numpy().astype('uint8'))

You're only viewing the [0] element of the images. Thats why its repeating 9 times.

Comment: What should I use instead?